# Simple EntityFramework with lambda and MySQL throws exception?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework 4 to remove some records from a MySQL database. This is my code :

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
                {
                    foreach (games_designer_binder binder in context.games_designer_binder.Where(c => c.gameId == inGameId))
                        context.games_designer_binder.DeleteObject(binder);

                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
```

This throws the following exception :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT\n     games_designer_binder.gameId, games_designer_binder. at line 1

Why? What Do I need to fix this?

**Edit:**

This works fine :

```
context.games_designer_binder.Where(c=> c.designerId == 22 && c.gameId == 1276).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I've seen other questions about EF not playing nicely with MySQL, but I don't know enough to help solve it.

Comment: The message indicates an error in SELECT so first try to just read some records.

Comment: @HenkHolterman How do you mean? Im able to run a stored Procedure with context.ExecuteStoreCommand but with the above code I get the select exception. Select is simple and should work even If I do not have the newest MySQL server.

Comment: Se my Edit1. The exception is not thrown until the context.SaveChanges is runned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you cannot delete an entity when you are iterating through the collection.

try this :

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
    {
        var binders = context.games_designer_binder.Where(c => c.gameId == inGameId).ToList();

        foreach (var binder in binders)
            context.games_designer_binder.DeleteObject(binder);

        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

note: I suggest you to change the games_designer_binder collection to reflect that it's actually a collection on model binder so it ends with an S, like : games_designer_binderS because you can mess it up with the collection and the entity itself.

Comment: go to page 18 http://iclass.iuea.ac.ug/intranet/E-books/INFORMATION%20TECHNOLOGY/SOFTWARE%20ENGINEERING/Addison%20Wesley%20-%20Analysis%20Patterns,%20Reusable%20Object%20Models%20(Object-Oriented%20Software%20Engineering%20.pdf

Comment: Ok, read the page 8 (link was dead but works now). I'm sorry I'm not sure I get what you are trying to tell me. Mind elavorate pls?

Comment: It was in reference to a different question you asked that got closed immediately before I posted that to you.